# Does any one know how to send and ephemeral message with disnake slash commands?

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
def sendBank():
    desc = """
    Bei dieser Nachricht kannst du auf die angefügten Buttons klicken, und damit diverse Funktionen ausführen.
    Wie zum Beispiel von der Bank Geld ausheben, Geld in die Bank einzahlen, wie auch anderen Spielern dein Geld überweisen.
    """
    
    embed = createEmbed(title="Unser Bankingsystem", description=desc, color=0x00ff0)
    return embed

@bot.slash_command(name="bank", description="Zeigt alle Commands von dem Bank System")
async def bank(inter):
    pc = Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Geld überweisen", custom_id="1", emoji="")
    withdraw = Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Geld auszahlen", custom_id="2", emoji="")
    deposit = Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Geld einzahlen", custom_id="3", emoji="")
    show = Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Geld anzeigen", custom_id="4", emoji="")
    await inter.channel.send(embed=sendBank(), components=[[pc, withdraw, deposit, show]], ephemeral=True)
```

So im trying to do this but then it shows me this error:

```
TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ephemeral'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elyes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\interaction_bot_base.py", line 1346, in process_application_commands
    await app_command.invoke(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\Elyes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 594, in invoke    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ephemeral'
```

I already tried to use other inter.*** methods (atributtes) but no one of them like acutally worked fine. I already read that you can only send ephemeral messages in Responses on interactions, so if you click a button.

If you try to help me, i am very thankful.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `inter.channel.send` to `inter.response.send_message`. All the arguments are the same

[Reference here](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/api.html?highlight=interaction#disnake.InteractionResponse.send_message)